# How can I make additions to this code to print a full triangle with my arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, drawing, arduino-c++

It obviously only makes half a triangle but I don't know how to fix that.
I'm new to this and honestly don't really know how to work it, so help would be greatly appreciated. 
I got this far but now I'm lost:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(100000); // timeout now is 100 seconds

  // read a number from serial port
  String s = Serial.readStringUntil(10); // read a line from serial port
  int n = s.toInt(); // convert the input string to integer value

for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<i+1; j++){
    Serial.print("*" );
   }

Serial.print("\n");
}

}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit incomplete, as it doesn't contain a [mcve] and doesn't say exactly what ouput you **get**, and how that is different to the output you **want**. Bear in mind that the Arduino code isn't really relevant here, you could produce your [mcve] using Standard C++, which would be easier for everyone else to test and help with. It looks to me like this will print a triangle, so could you please be clearer about what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace n with rows

```
for(int i = 1, k = 0; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0)
{
    for(space = 1; space <= rows-i; ++space)
    {
        cout <<"  ";
    }

    while(k != 2*i-1)
    {
        cout << "* ";
        ++k;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

here the output

https://ideone.com/OPMeO1